# How to debug shared webworkers?

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, web-worker

I am using shared webworkers, I am not getting the errors from the worker. The worker error handler not returning any errors!. How can I Debug shared webworkers.

```
var worker = new SharedWorker('Vult_worker.js');
    worker.port.start();
    worker.port.onerror = function(e) {
        consloe.log('ERROR: Line ', e.lineno, ' in ', e.filename, ': ', e.message);
    }

    worker.port.onmessage = function(e) {
        console.log(e.data);
    };
worker.port.postmessage();
```

worker Code:

```
onconnect = function(e) {
    var self = e.ports[0];
self.onmessage=function(){
self.postmessage(1/x);
}
```

Comment: What browser do you use? I don't see `SharedWorker` class on Firefox 13.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Navigate to `chrome://inspect/#workers` and find the shared worker and click on "inspect". Then you can pull up the console for the SharedWorker.

Comment: does anybody know how to open chrome://inspect in electron's BrowserWindow ?

Comment: Why isn't this the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is kinda old, Since then, Mozilla Firefox has implemented console.log in Shared Web Workers and Service Web Workers. See [Bug #1058644](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1058644).

Answer (score 0):

For Brave, navigate to `brave://inspect/#workers`